# Nonsense result from this SQL query using parameter.addwithvalue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

First of all, I'm using ASP.NET and whenever I execute the query on SQL Server it works just fine but when I execute it from ASP.NET it returns 0 rows - how is that even possible?

Here is my code:

asp.net :

```
List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
string value = "hello"
sql = "select a.id AID from article a where a.TheArticle like (N'%finder.aspx?hashtag=@data%')";

using (var sqlc = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data",value);

    using (var reader = sqlc.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tmp.Add(reader["AID"].ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the query on SQL Server:

```
select a.id 
from article a 
where a.TheArticle like (N'%finder.aspx?hashtag=hello%')
```

So this is begin to annoying me. What I think is `parameter.addwithvalue` instruction makes the SQL string just like this:

```
select a.id AID
from article a
where a.TheArticle like (N'%finder.aspx?hashtag='hello'%
```

I don't really know what has just happened so please someone explain it to me.

**Please**: I want to prevent SQL Injection as well

Comment: `@` parameters aren't supported inside string literals. Try explicit concatenation instead: `... like (N'%finder.aspx?hashtag=' + @data + '%')`

Comment: but this doesn't prevent sql injection

Comment: Yes it does. This use of string concatenation isn't creating dynamic SQL and so is safe (although % characters in `@data` would be misinterpreted by LIKE -- you would need to escape those characters).

Comment: so i keep using @data and bellow i use `parameter.addwithvalue("@data",value)`?

Comment: Yes, see if that works. And you can try including quotation marks in the value to verify that SQL injection isn't possible.

Comment: i didn't understand you mean `value="hello"` => `value="'hello'"`

Comment: Check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi: Yes, that should look for articles with hashtags containing single quotes. It should *not* cause a SQL error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
firstly modify the sql command as follow:

```
sql = "select a.id AID from article a where a.TheArticle like (N'%finder.aspx?hashtag=@data')"
```

then:

```
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", string.Concat(value, "%"));
```