# How to use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have been trying for hours and cannot find error in this sql query, getting exception "<"

```
            Connection con = new OrderManager.Connection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 

            string query = @"INSERT INTO [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder]
           ([OrderID]
           ,[Date]
           ,[Customer_Name]
           ,[Quality]
           ,[Color]
           ,[PCs]
           ,[Cutting]
           ,[TotalYards])
     VALUES
           (<OrderID, nvarchar(50),>
           ,<Date, varchar(25),>
           ,<Customer_Name, varchar(25),>
           ,<Quality, varchar(25),>
           ,<Color, varchar(25),>
           ,<PCs, varchar(25),>
           ,<Cutting, varchar(25),>
           ,<TotalYards, varchar(25),>)";

            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con.ActiveCon());

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", TxtBox_OrderID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", txtbox_CusName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quality", combo_Quality.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Color", combo_Color.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCs", updown_PCs.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cutting", combo_Cutting.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalYards", "Total Yards");
```

> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This is where error is throwing

```
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted", "Record Entered Successfully!");
```

---

I also tried using this but same problem.

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder] 
           (OrderID)
           ,(Date)
           ,(Customer_Name)
           ,(Quality)
           ,(Color)
           ,(PCs)
           ,(Cutting)
           ,(TotalYards)
     VALUES
           (@OrderID)
           ,(@Date)
           ,(@Customer_Name)
           ,(@Quality)
           ,(@Color)
           ,(@PCs)
           ,(@Cutting)
           ,(@TotalYards)";
```

Look at the code above and not sure what I am missing.

Comment: i am using connection class, where i have already opened connection, thats why using con.ActiveCon();

says incorrect syntax near "<"

Comment: lol - i see... In your VALUES list, supply the parameter names only... VALUES (@OrderID, @Date, etc...)

Comment: @flaZer i am too tired to see a problem..

Comment: you mean this? editing in main question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its C# and SQL Server.

Comment: unless you're on like c# 1.1 I think the preferred pattern is `cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderID").Value = TxtBox_OrderID.Text;`

Comment: `How to use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` - [please don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581529/nonsense-result-from-this-sql-query-using-parameter-addwithvalue#comment56908439_34581529).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stackoverflow was warning me about too many replies so i moved my response into an answer.

You used the template that SQL MGMT STUDIO gives you when you request it to give the SQL for an INSERT statement. The template it provides is not the actual insert statement but instead a guide to help you create the actual insert.  What I provided should be the "real" insert statement based on parameters you provided in c#.

Further, all parameters within the VALUES section should be enclosed within parenthesis, not each parameter individually.

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder]
           ([OrderID]
           ,[Date]
           ,[Customer_Name]
           ,[Quality]
           ,[Color]
           ,[PCs]
           ,[Cutting]
           ,[TotalYards])
     VALUES
           (@OrderID
           ,@Date
           ,@Customer_Name
           ,@Quality
           ,@Color
           ,@PCs
           ,@Cutting
           ,@TotalYards)";
```

One other point that has been raised in comments and other answers is that the **ORDERID** column... Because it's defined as `<OrderID, nvarchar(50)>`, strongly recommend the table design change so that the column is an **AUTO_INCREMENTED IDENTITY** column that users will not have the opportunity to modify.

For example, the TSQL definition should look:

```
[OrderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: whats the difference? from my question ?

Comment: please see my revised answer

Comment: But Parick has already tried this which is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: No he didn't - he enclosed each parameter in parenthesis.  The entire list should be enclosed , not each parameter individually.

Comment: flazer i am going to try your query now.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_NewOrder'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Neworder'

Comment: This is different because your VALUES section was using parenthesis incorrectly.

Comment: Remove @OrderID from the query in both spots (before the values where you list what you'll be inserting, as well in the values. If you have an auto-incrementing primary key.

Comment: Like @BRogers says, this is a different error.  The 1st time, SQLSERVER rejected your INSERT statement completely because your syntax was invalid.  This time, it accepted your SQL because it was properly formatted; however now, SQLSERVER is rejecting the insert because a "similar" record already exists in the database.  You;ll have to have a look at the table and determine how its primary key is defined, and once you know that, we can work towards the next step of solution :)

Comment: Another thing also is that the ORDERID is typically NOT an editable text field.  A 'ID' column in general, especially in the SQLSERVER world, is normally defined as an auto-incrementing IDENTITY column, and generally not passed as a parameter for insert.  Instead it's auto generated on the SQLSERVER side when a record is inserted into its table.

Comment: @flaZer . You have eagle eyes

Comment: Oh crud - wish I did!  It's not an identity column... <OrderID, nvarchar(50),>

Comment: flazer, how can I auto-increment Order ID with the word "OrderID00001" and 02 and 03 and 04...like that?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the PKey conflict:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO [MasterDatabase].[dbo].[Neworder]
           ([Date]
           ,[Customer_Name]
           ,[Quality]
           ,[Color]
           ,[PCs]
           ,[Cutting]
           ,[TotalYards])
     VALUES
           (@Date
           ,@Customer_Name
           ,@Quality
           ,@Color
           ,@PCs
           ,@Cutting
           ,@TotalYards)";
```

That should work. If not, it's because you have to generate a new `@OrderID` yourself that is unique so that you don't violate the constraint.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderID', table 'MasterDatabase.dbo.Neworder'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Is OrderID an `int`? edit the properties of that pkey and have it auto-increment. Or, prior to doing the insert, you will have to do a query to grab the last primary key from `dbo.Neworder` then increment it by one (if it's an int). If it's a GUID, you'll need to generate a new guid

Comment: It's not an identity... per his post it's <OrderID, nvarchar(50),>

Comment: @flazer i used nvarchar because I had to use "OrderID0001" otherwise it wouldn't  take. 

this procedure is being failed 'ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_Order_ID
AS
BEGIN
  Declare MaxNo int, No VarChar(50);
 Select MaxNo = ISNULL(Max(Cast(Right(OrderID, 5)as Int)), 0 + 1 from Neworder;
 Select 'Order#0000' + Right('00000' + Cast(MaxNo AS varchar), 5);
END'

Comment: Use @flaZer answer, and just make sure you're generating a unique orderid